# capybara click_link with :href match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have the following test in a request spec:

```
page.should have_link('Edit user', :href => edit_users_path(@user))
```

This checks that a specific user in an index view has an edit link.
I would like to click the same link, with something like:

```
click_link('Edit user', :href => edit_users_path(@user))
```

Unfortunately click_link doesn't accept options.

Is there a good way to do this, it seems like a fairly obvious use case?

Should I be including an #id in the table `<tr>` or `<td>` and doing something like:

```
within(#user_id)
  click_link 'Edit user'
end
```

I'd prefer not to tinker with the view just to get the tests to work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can use find `find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/foo']").click`

Comment: It seems a shame to have to drop down to the html level explicitly but this works, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You can use Capybara's lower level interface to do this. Try:

```
find("a[href='#{edit_users_path}']").click
```

Answer (score 13):

In 2021 it works as expected

```
click_link('...', href: '...')
click_link('...')
click_link(href: '...')
```

Comment: Nice! this is not easy to spot as it is not explicit in the docs but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L41) it uses `find` under the hood which is why the `click_link` method accepts the `href:` argument.

Comment: In 2022 this should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up adding a helper module in `spec/support/selectors.rb`

```
module Selectors
  Capybara.add_selector(:linkhref) do
    xpath {|href| ".//a[@href='#{href}']"}
  end
end
```

Then in the tests I use

```
find(:linkhref, some_path).click
```

Comment: How do you handle "have"?  i.e. page.should have_linkhref(...)

Comment: @vanboom You can define that method def have_linkhref(href)
  Capybara::RSpecMatchers::HaveSelector.new(:linkhref, href)
end And use like expect(page).to have_linkhref url

Answer (score 8):

Based on @jackpipe answer (and my previous experience) I build my own Capybara selector, here is the code for helper module (`spec/support/selectors.rb`):

```
module Selectors
  # find(:href, 'google.com')
  Capybara.add_selector(:href) do
    xpath {|href| XPath.descendant[XPath.attr(:href).contains(href)] }
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
find(:href, 'google')
```

What's the difference?

Well this will find any link which contains 'google'. The following will match:

```
www.google.com
http://google.com
fonts.google.com
something.google.inside.com
```

What's more it will search only among descendant selectors so e.g. `within('header') { find(:href, 'google').click }` will work correct.

Comment: Thanks, that's really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the first argument blank seems to work for me...

```
page.should have_link("", :href=>edit_comment_path(@comment))
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to *click* the link. He said that the "should have link" was working